# Hickory Dickory dock

Tags: lateral-thinking, animals

Hickory Dickory dock,
The MOUSE ran up the clock,
The clock struck one
The MOUSE ran down,
Hickory Dickory dock.

Hickory Dickory dock,
The OX ran up the clock,
The clock struck two
And down he flew,
Hickory Dickory dock.

Hickory Dickory dock,
The TIGER ran up the clock,
The clock struck three
And he did flee,
Hickory Dickory dock.

What animals come next ?

Comment: Love the premise and dynamic poetry! No comments yet? Guess the downvotes must be as mysterious to their grantors as they are to me.

Comment: My guess is that people downvoted because it was too simple. I like the new take on the "animals" theme though!

Comment: l upvoted it because it has too many downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Rabbit
>
> Dragon
>
> Snake
>
> Horse
>
> Goat
>
> Monkey
>
> Chicken
>
> Dog
>
> Pig
>
>  From Chinese astrology. the 12 zodiac animals

Answer (score 3):

> This is a "Hickory Dickory dock - zodiac animals" clock.
> [image: Hickory Dickory dock - zodiac animals" clock]

Answer (score 0):

4 - Rabbit
5 - Dragon
6 - Snake
7 - Horse
8 - Goat
9 - Monkey
10 - Rooster
11 - Dog
12 - Pig

Are these animals from the Chinese calendar ?